# In R Shiny create a button to perform an action

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App that runs with my script well. The script generated a table table. I wanted to add a function to save that data table to a location.
I looked and saw that actionButton and observeEvent to do the action. But the button is unresponsive. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my action button on the UI.R:

```
actionButton("action", "Download CSV Files")
```

Here is my observeEvent on the Server.R:

```
 observeEvent(input$action, {
        write.table(total_runCompletionStatus, file = "C:/total_runCompletionStatus.csv", sep = ",", col.names=TRUE)
        write.table(total_runParameters, file = "C:/total_runParameters.csv", sep = ",", col.names=TRUE)
        write.table(SEQ_QC_total, file = "C:/SEQ_QC.extracted.csv", sep = ",", col.names=TRUE)
      }

)
```

Comment: I think found the issue, it has to do with another button that was present. I wanted to use this button to run the analysis but apparently it was responding to the action variable. Do you know how I can have both buttons working together?

Comment: this was before action button
submitButton("Run Analysis"),

Comment: Can you try use downloadButton in ui.R and downloadHandler in server.R?http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html

Comment: You want to save files on server or on client PC?